# No migrations to apply in Django after changing class name in model.py

Tags: python, django

after i changed name of `class BillingAddress` To `class Address`. and tried these stages

1. Deleted all the migration records from your app's migration directory.
2. Also Deleted the db.sqlite3 file.

And Then, I did following commands

```py
python manage.py makemigrations core
python manage.py migrate
```

After migrated, Instead of showing data inserted ,it is shown
`No migrations to apply.` in Terminal

```py
PS C:\Users\Dell\project5> python manage.py makemigrations core
Migrations for 'core':
  core\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Address
    - Create model Coupon
    - Create model Item
    - Create model Order
    - Create model Refund
    - Create model Payment
    - Create model OrderItem
    - Add field items to order
    - Add field payment to order
    - Add field shipping_address to order
    - Add field user to order
PS C:\Users\Dell\project5> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, core, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
PS C:\Users\Dell\project5>
```

when i click `add to cart` button, it shown error as

> OperationalError at /add-to-cart/test-product-4/
>   table core_order has no column named shipping_address_id

model.py

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

# Create your models here.
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('SB', 'Shirts And Blouses'),
    ('TS', 'T-Shirts'),
    ('SK', 'Skirts'),
    ('HS', 'Hoodies&Sweatshirts')
)

LABEL_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'sale'),
    ('N', 'new'),
    ('P', 'promotion')
)

ADDRESS_CHOICES = (
    ('B', 'Billing'),
    ('S', 'Shipping')
)


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price

    def get_total_discount_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.discount_price

    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price() - self.get_total_discount_item_price()

    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.item.discount_price:
            return self.get_total_discount_item_price()
        return self.get_total_item_price()


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(
        'Address', related_name='shipping_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(
        'Address', related_name='billing_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(
        'Payment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(
        'Coupon', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    being_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_requested = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_granted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    '''
    1. Item added to cart
    2. Adding a BillingAddress
    (Failed Checkout)
    3. Payment
    4. Being delivered
    5. Received
    6. Refunds
    '''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        if self.coupon:
            total -= self.coupon.amount
        return total


class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField(multiple=False)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Address'


class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    amount = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code


class Refund(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reason = models.TextField()
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk}"
```

settting.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_countries',
    'core'
]
```

Comment: Did you add core to the INSTALLED_APPS setting?

Comment: i already added `core` in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Have you deleted db.sqlite3 that is really used by the app? That error happens because there are entities in the `django_migrations` table, so django thinks there are **no new migrations**. Please make sure you've deleted correct file. And update your question with the `databases` part of `settings.py`

Comment: i deleted `db.sqlite3` as i think django will auto built this file. i was wrong deleted the correct file. Where can i back up this file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be done all the time but you can delete all the migrations on the migrations folder BUT not delete the init.py. Afterwards, you can run migrations again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, delete all migrations file on your app core, not the init file.
Delete you database sqlite and your shell.
python manage.py migrate 
python manage.py makemigration and migrate